# Ball hitting a moving wall

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum, collision

I am pretty new so sorry in advance for any technical issues.
I was solving a problem from my book and I don't know how to solve it. If there is a ball moving at some velocity (let's say $v$) and it hits a wall moving at another velocity (let's say $u$)? What will happen to the balls kinetic energy, momentum and velocity? I tried to use the regular formula:

[image]

But the solution makes no sense. Can anybody explain this?
The example is the following. The mass of the ball is 1 kg and its speed is 5m/s, the speed of the wall is 1m/s. Find the speed of the ball after the ball hits
the wall(the collision is perfectly elastic) Can anybody explain this?

Comment: You must be given more data. What are the masses? What's the coefficient of restitution? What are the directions of the velocities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formulas do make perfect sense with the right approach. Consider $m_1$ is the mass of the ball and $m_2$ is the mass of the wall. What makes a moving wall a wall is that its mass is way greater than ball: $m_2\gg m_1$. We can rewrite formulas in terms of mass ratio $\frac{m_1}{m_2}$:

$$
v_1 = \frac{\frac{m_1}{m_2} - 1}{\frac{m_1}{m_2}+1}u_1 + \frac{2}{\frac{m_1}{m_2}+1}u_2,\qquad
v_2 = \frac{2\frac{m_1}{m_2}}{\frac{m_1}{m_2}+1}u_1 + \frac{1 - \frac{m_1}{m_2}}{\frac{m_1}{m_2}+1}u_2.
$$

Now if we consider the limit $\frac{m_1}{m_2} \to 0$, then the formulas become:
$$
v_1 = 2u_2 - u_1,\qquad v_2 = u_2
$$

How can we check the result with common sense?

1. Wall speed is the same after collision ($v_2=u_2$), which means that a small light ball cannot change the motion of a large massive wall.
2. If the wall is stationary ($u_2=0$), then $v_1=-u_2$, which means that ball bounces back with the same speed as expected.

I believe, you can know answer the questions about energy and momentum

Comment: Why are you assuming elastic collision? And why are you assuming same direction of velocities?

Comment: Because if there is “coefficient of restitution” or noncollinear velocities, the problem would have those stated. When physics textbook talks about “ball and wall”, it is safe to assume elastic collision.

Comment: What happpens if the wall is travelling in the same direction as the ball?

Comment: Just take $u_1$ negative

Comment: Thank you! But then the speed of the ball increases which I don't find intuitive.

Comment: If ball and wall were moving in one direction and still collided, then the wall was moving faster than the ball. Imagine a car hitting a man running away. Why isn't it intuitive that the ball will receive an additional push and increase the speed?